# QTableWidget. Некорректное отображение номера строчки, в которой нажата кнопка

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qtablewidget

Допустим есть приложение:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class StartingWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(StartingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn1.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)
        self.ui.btn2.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)
        self.ui.btn3.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)
        self.ui.btn4.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)

    def currentrow(self):
        buttonClicked = self.sender()
        index = self.ui.table.indexAt(buttonClicked.pos())
        print(buttonClicked.text())
        print(index.row())

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setRowCount(10)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, item)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn1.setText('btn1')

        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn2.setText('btn2')

        self.table.setCellWidget(0,0,self.btn1)
        self.table.setCellWidget(1,0,self.btn2)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.btn3.setText('btn3')
        self.btn4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.btn4.setText('btn4')
        self.hlay.addWidget(self.btn3)
        self.hlay.addWidget(self.btn4)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.hlay)
        self.table.setCellWidget(5, 0, self.widget)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)







app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
start_win = StartingWindow()

start_win.show()
sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

Метод `currentrow` должен отображать строчку из которой нажата кнопка. Кнопки `btn1`, `btn2` установлены как `cellWidget`, а `btn3` и `btn4` вставлены в `widget`, а он уже установлен как `cellWidget`. При нажатии на `btn1` и `btn2` номер строчки отображается корректно - `0` и `1` соответственно. При нажатии на `btn3` и `btn4` номер строки отображается некорректно и значение зависит от того, сколько строчек таблицы умещается на экране. Хотелось бы понять почему такое поведение? Очевидно, что дело в `widget`, но почему он вносит такое искажение и как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что при 0 и 1 строках кнопки имели в качестве родителя `viewport` таблицы, поэтому их позиции рассчитывались правильно.
А кнопки на 5 строке были внутри виджета и их позиция была относительно самого виджета `self.widget`, на который они были размещены

Решением будет использовать метод `mapToParent`:

```
def currentrow(self):
    buttonClicked = self.sender()

    parent = buttonClicked.parent()
    pos = parent.mapToParent(buttonClicked.pos())

    index = self.ui.table.indexAt(pos)
    print(buttonClicked.text())
    print(index.row())
```

Натыкал по кнопкам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запись `pos=parent.pos(`) вместо `pos = parent.mapToParent(buttonClicked.pos())` даст тот же самый результат?

Comment: @Skeggi, неа, при `parent.pos()`, позиция кнопок, которые одни на ячейку, будет всегда одинаковой и указывать на ячейку `0`x`0`

Answer (score 0):

Потому что [QWidget::pos](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop) возвращает координаты виджета относительно родительских (см. описание по ссылке), поэтому первые два батона выдают координаты относительно таблицы, а вторые два относительно родительского `QWidget`.
Что надо сделать? Надо перевести полученные координаты кнопки в координаты таблицы, независимо от того, какой виджет является для кнопки родителем.

Делается это при помощи методов [QWidget::mapToGlobal()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) и [QWidget::mapFromGlobal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapFromParent).

```py
def currentrow(self):
    buttonClicked = self.sender()

    # Глобальные координаты клика
    pos = buttonClicked.mapToGloabl(self.buttonClicked.pos())
    # Глобальные координаты в локально-табличные
    index = self.ui.table.indexAt(self.table.mapFromGlobal(pos))

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

По сути уже все объяснения даны, добавлю еще один возможный вариант.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setRowCount(10)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn1.setText('btn1')
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn2.setText('btn2')
       
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class StartingWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StartingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, item)
           
        self.table.setCellWidget(0, 0, self.btn1)
        self.table.setCellWidget(1, 0, self.btn2)  
        
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(                        # +++
            0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents
        )        

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ef8d32;')
       
        self.hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                                  # +++

        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.btn3.setText('btn3')
        self.btn4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.btn4.setText('btn4')
        self.hlay.addWidget(self.btn3)
        self.hlay.addWidget(self.btn4)
        self.table.setCellWidget(5, 0, self.widget)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(self.currentrow)

    def currentrow(self):
        buttonClicked = self.sender()
        btnText = buttonClicked.text()
        if btnText in ['btn3', 'btn4',]:
            index = self.table.indexAt(self.widget.pos())
        else:
            index = self.table.indexAt(buttonClicked.pos())
        
        print(f'btn -> {btnText}, row = {index.row()}, pos = {buttonClicked.pos()}')
#        print(buttonClicked.pos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = StartingWindow()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]